# How should I convert the following C# statement to vb.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have the following statement which I am trying to convert to vb.net. The assembly referenced was written in C# too.

The C# code is

```
  this.calendar1.DayHeaderClick += New System.Windows.Forms.Calendar.Calendar.CalendarDayEventHandler(this.calendar1_DayHeaderClick)
```

and I tried to write it as  in vb.net

```
 AddHandler this.calendar1.LoadItems, New EventHandler(AddressOf this.calendar1_LoadItems)
```

and

```
AddHandler this.calendar1.LoadItems, New EventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.Calendar.calendarl(this.calendar1_LoadItems))
```

I keep getting one or the other. One among them was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235221.aspx).

I am new to vb.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AddHandler this.calendar1.LoadItems, AddressOf this.calendar1_LoadItems`

Comment: Please post (all) error results as text in the message. That link is not very informative.

Comment: I got other errors like 'CalendarLoadEventHandler' is a type in 'System.Windows.Forms.Calendar.Calendar' and cannot be used as expression. 

Now I used the syntax suggested by @GSerg and it worked :)  thanks a bunch

Comment: +1 for showing you made an effort :)  OneFineDay's solution below should take care of you, though: `Me` instead of `this` for VB.

Comment: I have some 100 such statements and I didn't want to replace all of em with me...instead I made a declaration as 
`dim this=me`

Answer (score 5):

C# uses `this` to reference the form and VB uses `Me`.

```
AddHandler Me.calendar1.LoadItems, AddressOf Me.calendar1_LoadItems
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to choose the calendar1 in the codebehind window 
and then under declarations choose DayHeaderClick to let Visual studio generate the code.

You then get VB code that looks like :

```
 Private Sub MonthCalendar1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.KeyDown

 End Sub
```

Observe that I dont have acces to your Calendar-control so above is just an example.

Now I tried my own reccomendation and I got:

Imports System.Windows.Forms.Calendar

```
Private Sub Calendar1_DayHeaderClick(sender As Object, e As CalendarDayEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayHeaderClick

End Sub
```

Comment: that sounds like a good solution. Never thought of that.. I am using a customized control from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will 
Will the approach you say work for this control?

Comment: It should work... I have never tried to automatically do that with a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following website. It is pretty good:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/